# Find radius such that packing circles into a fixed rectangle maximises total area of circles

Tags: calculus, optimization, circles, packing-problem

I want to pack equal-sized circles into a rectangle with width $w$, and height $h$. The total area of all of the circles should be maximised.

the radius of each circle can vary, but is contrained; $r\in[a,b]$

How do I go about solving this?

Would be great if I can get help with that general case. If not, the following specific case would also be good.

$w=11.2$   $h=2.8$   $a=0.45$  $b=0.9$

Thank you!

**edit**:

I also want the circles to be packed like this

[image]

tell me if I'm wrong, but so far I've done the following;

Suppose there are $x$ circles across the bottom width. Then the total length of all the circles is $2rx$.

Suppose the stack is $y$ "layers" of circles high. Then the hight of the stack is $r(\sqrt{3}(y-1)+2)$

So we have

$2rx=w$

$r(\sqrt{3}(y-1)+2)\leq{h}$

or

$2rx\leq{w}$

$r(\sqrt{3}(y-1)+2)=h$

Comment: Does every circle have to be contained entirely in the rectangle?

Comment: That was a pretty dumb question, sorry. They obviously do, otherwise you would just choose one that contained the rectangle.

Comment: This looks like an enormously difficult problem to me. To get the flavour of it, see [this Wikipedia article on packing squares with circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing_in_a_square).

Comment: Sorry Tony, I forgot to mention I also want the circle's to be packed the hexagonal way. Maybe it's a bit easier now? still very difficult for me.

Comment: One of your two inequalities is an equation - they fit exactly, either horizontally or vertically - otherwise you could make the circles bigger.

Comment: Thank you Michael, good spotting.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by means of integer programming regarded the size of the input is not too large.

Details, problem formulations and numerical experiments can be found [here](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2014/317697/).

Answer (score 0):

I came across this page while working on a similar problem for the automated controls on a spooled cable. I'm solving a different problem, but I'll just address the height calculation in my answer.

Your solution looks pretty close and gets the trig right, except it doesn't pass my fat finger sanity test for height.

Its helpful to define each step on the inside as r√3 and just count them.

If we plug y=3;r=1, we get h = √3(3-1)+2 = 2√3+2. If I take my finger and plop it on the graphic counting radii, this tells the story of a full radius to the center of the bottom circle, then √3 up to the top of the first layer, then another √3 to the middle of the middle layer, then a full radius up. Thats only 2 layers...

Starting from the bottom edge of the first row, we get 1 full radius, then twice r√3 up to the center of the next layer, then twice r√3 again to the center of the top layer, then another full radius. So we lose one layer to full radii and count the rest by root3s. This becomes

height = 2r+2r√3(y-1) = r(2√3(y-1)+2) for 0<y

plugging in y=3 yields 2r + 4r√3.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).